# _POST_FLAT_FILE_INVLOADER_DATA_ feed: Ship option ' * ' is invalid

Tags: amazon-mws

Since the recent shipping settings change (made by Amazon, not us), we have been having some problems with our _POST_FLAT_FILE_INVLOADER_DATA_ feed (and have made no changes our end).

**Below is an example feed sent (the spaces are tabs, it just shows like this here):**

```
sku product-id  product-id-type price   minimum-seller-allowed-price    maximum-seller-allowed-price    item-condition  quantity    add-delete  will-ship-internationally   expedited-shipping  item-note   fulfillment-center-id   merchant-shipping-group-name
7564    B003TL29BU  1   16.46           11  518 a   3   3
7648    B003R7JSKG  1   57.52           11  54  a   3   3
11544   B003ZGF7NG  1   5.30            11  0   a   3   3
12144   B001LJA5AO  1   5.11            11  331 a   3   3
13099   B004WJ0KIC  1   17.88           11  330 a   3   3
20700   B00G9EQP3M  1   6.30            11  300 a   3   3
20931   B0012TUWQA  1   5.73            11  610 a   3   3
20932   B002EDNJHM  1   6.20            11  6   a   3   3
20934   B002DKRF2Q  1   12.20           11  610 a   3   3
21031   B007YZMGYW  1   8.15            11  601 a   3   3
21033   B00FEFMLFS  1   9.97            11  610 a   3   3
21034   B00FEFMLWQ  1   17.88           11  305 a   3   3
21036   B00FEFMMCU  1   29.96           11  302 a   3   3
21046   B011AFU39G  1   13.92           11  309 a   3   3
23382   B0085N3K4M  1   10.64           11  303 a   3   3
23421   B0080N6OKE  1   16.02           11  300 a   3   3
25633   B0033XDZJY  1   5.84            11  10  a   3   3
25634   B008719D70  1   7.67            11  309 a   3   3
25635   B007YZRQ4C  1   5.67            11  6   a   3   3
25636   B007YZRQNI  1   7.97            11  310 a   3   3
25657   B00803CXKO  1   9.89            11  17  a   3   3
25658   B00871OCCQ  1   18.59           11  7   a   3   3
25666   B007YZLUVW  1   7.10            11  310 a   3   3
26324   B003FTU1W0  1   6.98            11  308 a   3   3
29377   B0042MI6AS  1   32.81           11  330 a   3   3
29379   B004WJ0L3Q  1   20.97           11  628 a   3   3
29380   B004WJ0KVE  1   22.88           11  331 a   3   3
29381   B004WJ0H9O  1   20.95           11  330 a   3   3
29382   B004WJ0HEE  1   21.25           11  330 a   3   3
29383   B004WJ0HPI  1   19.30           11  630 a   3   3
29384   B004WJ0HVM  1   19.30           11  330 a   3   3
29385   B004WJ0I20  1   21.97           11  630 a   3   3
29387   B004WJ0II4  1   27.24           11  330 a   3   3
29388   B004WJ0IPM  1   27.24           11  630 a   3   3
29389   B004WJ0IUC  1   37.02           11  330 a   3   3
29390   B004WJ0KAU  1   32.88           11  330 a   3   3
32230   B004WDOTV2  1   25.57           11  64  a   3   3
37048   B00JUYP6DS  1   26.35           11  30  a   3   3
37927   B00P06NFF6  1   5.77            11  310 a   3   3
39949   B003ESMDOG  1   5.20            11  53  a   3   3
41208   B00KOI8NU2  1   8.17            11  30  a   3   3
41944   B00N99CWIM  1   14.34           11  60  a   3   3
42006   B00PITPZI0  1   21.53           11  82  a   3   3
45015   B00NIT9L9G  1   11.24           11  31  a   3   3
49224   B00PIUNSJC  1   14.21           11  31  a   3   3
71765   B007G9AJJU  1   16.43           11  2   a   3   3
```

**And below here is the output of the errors from Amazon. We don't really understand why shipping options would suddenly be invalid and are not actually specifying any shipping options in the feed anyway.**

```
Feed Processing Summary:
    Number of records processed     46
    Number of records successful        4

original-record-number  sku error-code  error-type  error-message
1   7564    8005    Error   You are attempting to change an identity attribute for this SKU. To proceed, please delete this SKU and recreate the SKU with the appropriate identity attribute. For more information and detailed instructions, see: http://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/23191
1   7564    13013   Error   This SKU does not exist in your Amazon inventory so we could not process this record. To correct this error for future feeds, add the SKU to your Amazon account. For more information, see http://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/errorcode/13013.
1   7564    33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
1   7564    33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
1   7564    33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
1   7564    33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
1   7564    33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
10  21031   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
10  21031   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
10  21031   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
10  21031   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
10  21031   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
11  21033   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
11  21033   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
11  21033   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
11  21033   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
11  21033   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
12  21034   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
12  21034   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
12  21034   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
12  21034   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
12  21034   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
13  21036   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
13  21036   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
13  21036   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
13  21036   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
13  21036   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
14  21046   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
14  21046   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
14  21046   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
14  21046   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
14  21046   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
15  23382   8101    Error   Invalid ProductType value for SKU: [23382]. For help fixing this, see http://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/errorcode/8101
16  23421   8101    Error   Invalid ProductType value for SKU: [23421]. For help fixing this, see http://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/errorcode/8101
16  23421   13013   Error   This SKU does not exist in the Amazon.com catalog. Your inventory data was not processed. For reasons why, and help fixing this, see http://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/errorcode/13013
17  25633   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
17  25633   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
17  25633   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
17  25633   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
17  25633   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
18  25634   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
18  25634   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
18  25634   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
18  25634   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
18  25634   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
19  25635   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
19  25635   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
19  25635   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
19  25635   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
19  25635   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
2   7648    33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
2   7648    33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
2   7648    33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
2   7648    33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
2   7648    33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
20  25636   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
20  25636   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
20  25636   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
20  25636   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
20  25636   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
21  25657   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
21  25657   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
21  25657   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
21  25657   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
21  25657   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
22  25658   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
22  25658   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
22  25658   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
22  25658   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
22  25658   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
23  25666   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
23  25666   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
23  25666   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
23  25666   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
23  25666   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
24  26324   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
24  26324   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
24  26324   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
24  26324   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
24  26324   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
25  29377   90202   Error   There is a restriction in effect at the item level (because of Item-Level gatings on an offer)
26  29379   90202   Error   There is a restriction in effect at the item level (because of Item-Level gatings on an offer)
27  29380   90202   Error   There is a restriction in effect at the item level (because of Item-Level gatings on an offer)
28  29381   90202   Error   There is a restriction in effect at the item level (because of Item-Level gatings on an offer)
29  29382   90202   Error   There is a restriction in effect at the item level (because of Item-Level gatings on an offer)
3   11544   8058    Error   The following attributes are missing for SKU: [11544]: '[manufacturer]'.For more details, see http://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/errorcode/8058
30  29383   90202   Error   There is a restriction in effect at the item level (because of Item-Level gatings on an offer)
31  29384   90202   Error   There is a restriction in effect at the item level (because of Item-Level gatings on an offer)
32  29385   90202   Error   There is a restriction in effect at the item level (because of Item-Level gatings on an offer)
33  29387   90202   Error   There is a restriction in effect at the item level (because of Item-Level gatings on an offer)
34  29388   90202   Error   There is a restriction in effect at the item level (because of Item-Level gatings on an offer)
35  29389   90202   Error   There is a restriction in effect at the item level (because of Item-Level gatings on an offer)
36  29390   90202   Error   There is a restriction in effect at the item level (because of Item-Level gatings on an offer)
37  32230   8567    Error   SKU 32230 does not match any ASIN and contains invalid values for attributes required for creation of a new ASIN.  New ASIN creation requires the following attributes, for which this SKU provided invalid attribute value(s): merchant_suggested_asin.
37  32230   13013   Error   This SKU does not exist in the Amazon.com catalog. Your inventory data was not processed. For reasons why, and help fixing this, see http://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/errorcode/13013
38  37048   8058    Error   The following attributes are missing for SKU: [37048]: '[manufacturer]'.For more details, see http://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/errorcode/8058
39  37927   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
39  37927   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
39  37927   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
39  37927   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
39  37927   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
4   12144   8005    Error   You are attempting to change an identity attribute for this SKU. To proceed, please delete this SKU and recreate the SKU with the appropriate identity attribute. For more information and detailed instructions, see: http://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/23191
4   12144   13013   Error   This SKU does not exist in your Amazon inventory so we could not process this record. To correct this error for future feeds, add the SKU to your Amazon account. For more information, see http://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/errorcode/13013.
4   12144   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
4   12144   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
4   12144   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
4   12144   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
4   12144   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
40  39949   8058    Error   The following attributes are missing for SKU: [39949]: '[item_name]'.For more details, see http://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/errorcode/8058
41  41208   8058    Error   The following attributes are missing for SKU: [41208]: '[item_name]'.For more details, see http://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/errorcode/8058
42  41944   8058    Error   The following attributes are missing for SKU: [41944]: '[item_name]'.For more details, see http://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/errorcode/8058
43  42006   8058    Error   The following attributes are missing for SKU: [42006]: '[item_name]'.For more details, see http://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/errorcode/8058
44  45015   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
44  45015   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
44  45015   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
44  45015   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
44  45015   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
45  49224   8058    Error   The following attributes are missing for SKU: [49224]: '[manufacturer]'.For more details, see http://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/errorcode/8058
46  71765   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
46  71765   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
46  71765   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
46  71765   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
46  71765   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
5   13099   90202   Error   There is a restriction in effect at the item level (because of Item-Level gatings on an offer)
6   20700   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
6   20700   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
6   20700   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
6   20700   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
6   20700   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
7   20931   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
7   20931   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
7   20931   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
7   20931   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
7   20931   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
8   20932   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
8   20932   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
8   20932   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
8   20932   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
8   20932   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
9   20934   33033   Error   Ship option 'Exp UK Domestic' is invalid.
9   20934   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Domestic' is invalid.
9   20934   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK Europe' is invalid.
9   20934   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK NorthAmerica' is invalid.
9   20934   33033   Error   Ship option 'Std UK-ROW' is invalid.
```

Here is a screenshot from our seller central showing our shipping options. Not sure if this is relevant or not.

[image: Seller Central shipping options]

I hope you can help.

Thanks in advance.

Luke

Comment: In case anyone is reading this with the same problem. I've contacted Amazon about it and they seem equally confused. https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1345114&#1345114 If I get a solution, I'll post it here too.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the new shipping template name you have created in the field

```
merchant-shipping-group-name
```

i.e use    Amazon Shipping 
and please note that as per the new shipping settings the shipping override will not work. You have to create an extra shipping template to achieve the same. Amazon allows up to 20 templates